# Binding event before Creating DOM in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, append

```
var thumbDom = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  thumbDom = thumbDom + '<div id = "div-" ' + i + '>DIV-'+ i +'</div>';
  bindEvent(i);
}

$('#parent').append(thumbDom);


function bindEvent(i){
  $('#div-' + i).click(function(event) {
        alert(i);
  });
}
```

I know the code can't work , beacuse event is bind before dom append.
but is there anyway to bind the click event to many dynamically doms before appending to dom tree?

I don't wnat to use $(document).on('click, ... , I want to bind event to the child node.

Any suggest will be help , thank you~

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ryan119/xc9L0wa9/1/)

Comment: `I don't wnat to use $(document).on('click, ... , I want to bind event to the child node.` Why? Event delegation is *exactly* the pattern to use here.

Comment: Invoke `bindEvent` after `.append` but @RoryMcCrossan is right as I could not find any reason to avoid that pattern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach:

- define a `<div></div>`
- set its `id` and `innerHtml`
- bind it with an `onclick` event (that alerts its `id`)
- append it to the "#parent" item

---

```
$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("<div></div>")
            .attr("id", "div-" + i)
            .html("DIV-" + i)
            .click(function() {
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
            })
            .appendTo("#parent");
    }
});
```